How to set a user password in Active Directory using LDAP Delphi component from IPWorks
I need to set a user password in Active Directory using LDAP Delphi component from IPWorks.
I'm using the code shown below. It works without error, but I can't login in AD because it does not recognize the password.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

   ipwLDAP.DN := 'CN=Test Delphi,OU=ERP,OU=Users and Groups,DC=AD,DC=INTERNAL' ;

   ipwLDAP.AttrCount    := 1 ;

   ipwLDAP.AttrType[0]   := 'userPassword' ;
   ipwLDAP.AttrValueB[0] := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes( 'xyz@12345678' ) ;
   ipwLDAP.AttrModOp[0]  := amoReplace ;

   ipwLDAP.Modify ;

   ShowMessage(ipwLDAP.ResultDescription ) ;

end;

I tried use unicodePwd but I get this error :

Error: 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A124C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

   ipwLDAP.DN := 'CN=Test Delphi,OU=UsersERP,OU=Users and Groups,DC=AD,DC=INTERNAL' ;

   ipwLDAP.AttrCount    := 1 ;

   ipwLDAP.AttrType[0]   := 'unicodePwd' ;
   ipwLDAP.AttrValueB[0] := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes( 'xyz@12345678' ) ;
   ipwLDAP.AttrModOp[0]  := amoReplace ;

   ipwLDAP.Modify ;

   ShowMessage(ipwLDAP.ResultDescription ) ;

end;

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?
Thanks for any help

Maybe helpful: https://developer.sailpoint.com/discuss/t/iqservice-refuse-to-set-password/23743 - one potential reason: new password does not meet minimum password complexity policy.

Thanks for replying !
About password policy isn't the problem because it works when I put this password manually and follow login.
I saw your link and there is a list of error messages that will be usefull.
Anyway, thanks!
